# Error " more columns than column names" when attempting to read data from the Global Terrorism Database

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to read data from the Global Terrorism Database in R.
I downloaded it as an xslx file, and used excel to export it to csv.

I then run the code:

`"Terror_Data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\egen9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\UiO\\Bachelor\\Kilder\\R\\Data\\globalterrorismdb_0718distcsv.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)"`.

And get the error:

> "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  :   more columns than column names"

I have attempted to force excel to use "." as a separator, and removed `"sep = ",",` and also tried without `"header = true"` but that doesn't change anything.
Have also checked the headers in the file for spaces, forbidden characters, and data without a header without finding anything.

Comment: I find it's best to export from excel to a tab-delimited format and read it like that. Or, better yet, just use `read_xlsx` from the tidyverse `readxl` package.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the readx1 package, but that did solve my problem. However, it is somewhat slow (used nearly a minute just to read the file), any tips on how to get it more efficient if possible?

Comment: I've never known it to be particularly slow. How big is the file?

Comment: The file is about 240MB, it's the Global Terrorism Dataset from the University of Maryland. –

Comment: If you know you don't need all the cells, you can probably make things quicker by setting the `range` attribute in the read_xlsx command, but other than that I don't know. Once you've loaded it one time you can save write.csv it and load from that next time?